# Running a sample script using Robot Framework

Tags: frameworks, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am fairly new to Robot Framework. I am trying to run the following code using Ride IDE but facing issues. Could someone kindly help me on how to get this done.

Code:

```
*** Settings ***

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Setting Variables
    #| Example of running a python script
    ${result}=    run process | python | C:\Users\name\Desktop\hello.py
    #| | Should be equal as integers | ${result.rc} | 0
    #| | Should be equal as strings    | ${result.stdout} | Hello World

*** Keywords ***
```

Comment: Welcome. What issues are you facing? Please edit your question and add all relevant error messages you're getting.

Comment: I am just trying to execute a sample test for hello world program wriiten in Python. I am unable to figure how to do the same. Kindly help.

Comment: But when you execute your RF script, what error do you get?

Comment: The following is the comment I  get.
20200723 12:07:07.335 :  FAIL : No keyword with name 'Run Process' found.

Comment: So see my answer, it answers your question. You're missing a library import. This keyword is available in `Process` library, you don't import this library.

Comment: As you can see, I have declared Library Process under Settings section. Still facing the issue.

Comment: @Diasppra: I actually don't see that. No code you have showed contains that.

Comment: please share the new code where under the setting section you import the library Process

if you still encounter the same issue after importing the library,
replace 'run process' with 'Run Process'

Answer (score 1):

I still think you should include more details in your question, namely:

- the content of `hello.py`
- the error message you get

Nevertheless, I think your problem will be somewhere around these:

1/ Your Settings section is empty, but you need `Process` library in order to execute `Run Process` keyword.

2/ Your `hello.py` is wrong, doesn't return and print what you think it does.

3/ You absolute path is wrong, the python file resides somewhere else.

4/ You're missing some modules you need in order to execute RF scripts. Please search on this site, similar question about missing modules has been asked many times.

All in all, the whole runnable example (provided you have all the prerequisites installed) would be:

```
*** Settings *** 
Library    Process    

*** Test Cases *** 
Setting Variables
    ${result}=    Run Process    python    hello.py
    Should be equal as integers    ${result.rc}    0
    Should be equal as strings    ${result.stdout}    Hello World
```

It's a good practice not to use absolute paths, so I refer to `hello.py` differently. The content of the file is:

**hello.py**

```py
print('Hello World')
```

Comment: Dear Sir, Sorry if I appear naive. I am trying to run this single line.
${result} = run process python    -c    print 'Hello World!'

When I run, I get this error as below.
===================================================================Setting Variables                                                                                                    | FAIL |
Test case contains no keywords.
${result} = run process python                                                                                       | FAIL |
No keyword with name '-c' found

Comment: If you copy-paste my example, it should work. Start with that and add more to it.